Anuloma in Kaliyuga
I've heard that Anuloma marriages in Kaliyuga come with stringent restrictions. Specifically, as a man, you can only marry someone one level below your varna (for example, a Brahman male will only marry a Kshatriya woman, and a Kshatriya man can only marry a Vaishya woman). Moreover, in most cases, the offspring of anuloma marriages would typically inherit the caste of the mother. I'm interested in finding some scriptural references that support these claims.

While some state that in case of anuloma marriage, the offspring is of the same caste as of its mother, in practice the offspring belongs to the caste of the father. Otherwise Vedavyasa, Jamadagni & Parashurama can't be considered as brahmins, the offspring of Yayati through Devayani can't be considered as kshatriyas.

None of them was born in Kaliyuga.

The Smritis, by Hindu cosmology, are also not of Kaliyuga. So you can also say that their mandates are also non-applicable. Besides, if the offspring of intercaste unions didn't bear the caste of its father, it would create a situation where children born from viloma marriages (despised in the scriptures) would be considered as high caste, especially in case of chandalas (born from the union of a brahmin woman & shudra man).

If you want an example from Kaliyuga, then take the case of king Girvana Yuddha Vikrama Shah of Nepal, who was the illegitimate son of King Rana Bahadur Shah through his Maithili brahmin concubine Kantimati Jha. He was considered to belong to his father's caste of Khas Arya & not a brahmin. Mind you, Nepal at that time was a truly Hindu state, with all laws derived from Hindu scriptures.

That is an example of Pratiloma, not Anuloma
